# QPDF: reversing order of files to be appended via globbing qualifier

Tags: command-line, bash, pdf

Context: 16.04

A `qpdf` example indicates:

```
# To merge (concatenate) all the pages of a list of PDF files and save the result as a new PDF:
qpdf --empty --pages <file1.pdf> <file2.pdf> <file3.pdf> -- <output.pdf>
```

A set of .pdf files (with spaces in filenames), in a particular directory, are to be concatenated:

```
# Concatenate Drafts file to ../concatDrafts.pdf   (76 pdf files)
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/53754681/4953146
qpdf --empty --pages *.pdf -- out.pdf
```

Although [`qpdf` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/617493/182280) is concatenates .pdf files, the reverse order of the .pdf files is to be concatenated.  The order of the files to be processed is returned by in UNIX:

```
ls -r.pdf
```

Is there a BASH equivalent globbing qualifier for the [zsh statement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/617493/182280)?:

```
qpdf --empty --pages ./*.pdf(On) -- output.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK bash has no such qualifier. You could use an external `sort` command ex. assuming a sufficiently recent version of bash that supports a null-terminated mapfile:

```
mapfile -d '' -t files < <(printf '%s\0' ./*.pdf | sort -zr)

qpdf --empty --pages "${files[@]}" -- output.pdf
```

Note that if you want a reverse *numeric* sort, equivalent to the zsh `(nOn)` qualifier, you would need to use `sort -zVr` rather than the plain numeric `sort -znr` since `sort` won't look past a non-numeric prefix.